# Split Array to Arrays by value Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have array thay contains data like this: [value]#[mode] (mode is optional)

I want to split this array to arrays of [value] by [mode] but keeping the same position for data so it can be many array for same mode :

ex:

```
let array = ["23.88", "24", "30",  "24.16#C", "25#C", "12#C", "24.44#O", "50#O" , "31", "40" , "44#C", "55#C"]  

// Result 

No mode  ---> [23.88,24,30] 
mode = C ---> [24.16,25,12]
mode = O ---> [24.44,50]
No mode  ---> [31,40] 
mode = C ---> [44,55]
```

I tried this extension but is not what i want

```
extension SequenceType {
    func groupBy<U : Hashable>(@noescape keyFunc: Generator.Element -> U) -> [U:[Generator.Element]] {
        var dict: [U:[Generator.Element]] = [:]
        for el in self {
            let key = keyFunc(el)
            if case nil = dict[key]?.append(el) { dict[key] = [el] }
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

it give me result like this :

```
No mode  ---> [23.88,24,30,31,40] 
mode = C ---> [24.16,25,12,44,55]
mode = O ---> [24.44,50]
```

Comment: I tried extension GroupBy but is not what i want. I updated my post

Comment: Swift dictionaries require keys to be unique.  If you want to generate your results using a dictionary the way you have them broken up you would need to instead have a key map to an array of arrays.

Comment: why 24.44 not in same array as 23.88? in your expected result arrays

Comment: We need your `keyFunc` code and the actual invocation of your extension method.

Comment: Also your claimed desired result doesn't match your input. "31" and "40" are the "O" mode, not "No mode" in the input.

Comment: Sorry i fixed the array, my mistake

Comment: I can create a solution to this, but it might be later this evening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify the `groupBy` extension to group into an array of 2-tuples rather than an dictionary, where the first tuple element corresponds to a non-unique "key", and the 2nd tuple element is an array of subsequent elements in the `self` array that can be categorized to the given key.

***Modified `SequenceType` extension***

```
extension SequenceType {
    func groupBy<U : Comparable>(@noescape keyFunc: Generator.Element -> U) -> [(U,[Generator.Element])] {
        var tupArr: [(U,[Generator.Element])] = []
        for el in self {
            let key = keyFunc(el)
            if tupArr.last?.0 == key {
                tupArr[tupArr.endIndex-1].1.append(el)
            }
            else {
                tupArr.append((key,[el]))
            }
        }
        return tupArr
    }
}
```

Note also that is now suffices that the generic `U` in the extension conforms to `Comparable`, as we only use the `U` elements as "fake" keys in a tuple.

***Call to extension***

With this modification, we can call the `groupBy(..)` method as

```
let array = ["23.88", "24", "30",  "24.16#C", "25#C", "12", "24.44", "50" , "31#O", "40#O" , "44#C", "55#C"]

/* assuming we know the last character always describe the mode,
   given one is included (#) */
let groupedArray: [(String,[String])] = array.groupBy {
    guard $0.characters.contains("#") else { return "No mode" }
    return "mode = " + String($0.characters.last!)
}

print(groupedArray)
/* [("No mode", ["23.88", "24", "30"]), 
    ("mode = C", ["24.16#C", "25#C"]), 
    ("No mode", ["12", "24.44", "50"]), 
    ("mode = O", ["31#O", "40#O"]), 
    ("mode = C", ["44#C", "55#C"])] */
```

***Removing original mode markings (`#X`) from grouped array***

If you'd like to remove original mode markings (`#X`) in the resulting array, you can apply an additional `map` operation following the call to `groupBy`.

Removing markings with resulting values as `String`:

```
let groupedArrayClean = groupedArray.map { ($0.0, $0.1.map {
    String($0.characters.prefixUpTo($0.characters.indexOf("#") ?? $0.characters.endIndex))
    })
}

print(groupedArrayClean)
/* [("No mode", ["23.88", "24", "30"]), 
    ("mode = C", ["24.16", "25"]), 
    ("No mode", ["12", "24.44", "50"]), 
    ("mode = O", ["31", "40"]), 
    ("mode = C", ["44", "55"])] */
```

Or, with resulting values as `Double`:

```
let groupedArrayClean = groupedArray.map { ($0.0, $0.1.flatMap {
    Double(
        String(($0.characters.prefixUpTo($0.characters.indexOf("#") ?? $0.characters.endIndex))))
    })
}

print(groupedArrayClean)
/* [("No mode", [23.879999999999999, 24.0, 30.0]), 
    ("mode = C", [24.16, 25.0]), 
    ("No mode", [12.0, 24.440000000000001, 50.0]), 
    ("mode = O", [31.0, 40.0]), 
    ("mode = C", [44.0, 55.0])] */
```

***Alternatively: group and clean up mode markings in single chained call***

Or, both `groupBy` followed by `map` at once, without an intermediate assignment:

```
let groupedArrayClean: [(String,[String])] = array.groupBy {
    guard $0.characters.contains("#") else { return "No mode" }
    return "mode = " + String($0.characters.last!)
    }
    .map { ($0.0, $0.1.map {
        String($0.characters
            .prefixUpTo($0.characters.indexOf("#") ?? $0.characters.endIndex))
        })
}
```

(Analogously for the resulting `Double` values case.)

Comment: So far this is the best answer IMO. Adds on to OP's current function without tons of code and does exactly what it should do.

Comment: @HaydenHolligan I should agree. Thought, when I started to write my answer, there was no any function provided by OP.

Comment: @ShadowOf fair point. Yours does the same thing and works but there's definitely more code than necessary, function or not

Comment: @OuSS Happy to help!

Comment: Those abbreviations (`keyFunc`, `tupArr`, `el`) aren't very Swifty... Nice solution otherwise!

Comment: @TimVermeulen indeed; motivated by the intent of trying to modify the OPs own extension as little as possible (and with the inclusions on my own `tupleArr` following the same non-Swifty name convention as the original code: type explanatory).

Comment: I think that only encourages and reinforces bad practices.

Comment: @TimVermeulen to the point of downvoting? If that criteria were sufficient to downvote answers, there's alot of downvoting cut out for those up for that... I'm only at a mobile device but you're welcome to update the answer with parameter names you deem more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I offer you to use array with tuples (to hold keys). Compose this array and then you easily can remap it to format you need:

```
let array = ["23.88", "24", "30",  "24.16#C", "25#C", "12#C", "24.44#O", "50#O" , "31", "40" , "44#C", "55#C"]

let noModeTag = "#NoMode"

func group(array: [String]) -> [(String, [Double])]
{
    var result = [(String, [Double])]()

    func addNextElement(number: Double?, _ mode: String?) {
        guard let number = number, mode = mode else {fatalError("input format error")}
        if result.last?.0 == mode {
            var array = result.last!.1
            array.append(number)
            result[result.count - 1] = (mode, array)
        } else {
            result.append((mode, [number]))
        }
    }

    for element in array {
        if element.containsString("#") {
            let separated = element.componentsSeparatedByString("#")
            addNextElement(Double(separated.first ?? "_"), separated.last)
        } else {
            addNextElement(Double(element), noModeTag)
        }
    }
    return result
}

print(group(array))
//[("#NoMode", [23.88, 24.0, 30.0]), ("C", [24.16, 25.0, 12.0]), ("O", [24.44, 50.0]), ("#NoMode", [31.0, 40.0]), ("C", [44.0, 55.0])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
func newArray(incomeArray:[String], index: Int) -> [String: [String]] {
    let modeArray = incomeArray[index].componentsSeparatedByString("#")
    let currentMode = modeArray.count > 1 ? modeArray.last : "No mode"
    var arr: [String] = []
    for i in index...incomeArray.count-1 {
        let modeArray = incomeArray[i].componentsSeparatedByString("#")
        let mode = modeArray.count > 1 ? modeArray.last : "No mode"
        if mode == currentMode || (mode == "" && currentMode == "") {
            arr.append(modeArray.first!)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return ["Mode = " + currentMode!: arr];
}


let array: [String] = ["23.88", "24", "30",  "24.16#C", "25#C", "12", "24.44", "50" , "31#O", "40#O" , "44#C", "55#C"]

var index = 0
while index < array.count {
    let dict = newArray(array, index: index)
    print(dict)
    index += dict[Array(dict.keys).first!]!.count
}
```

result:

```
["Mode = No mode": ["23.88", "24", "30"]]
["Mode = C": ["24.16", "25"]]
["Mode = No mode": ["12", "24.44", "50"]]
["Mode = O": ["31", "40"]]
["Mode = C": ["44", "55"]]
```

Comment: This will give me array with all #C mode, but i want to keep the same order of values. if #C are separated then i need 2 arrays of #C

Comment: So, you need new array every time when #mode changed?

Comment: Yes that what i want

Comment: This is incomplete. You would have to call this multiple times on the array and doesn't do what OuSS is asking

Answer (score 0):

Six years later, there's still no simple way to get this kind of segmentation. At least I'm not aware of any. I came across this issue today and here's how I solved it (in 2022, using Swift 5+).

Implementation is a an extension to `Collection`:

```
extension Collection {
    func segments<Eq: Equatable>(_ key: @escaping (Element) -> Eq) -> AnySequence<SubSequence> {
        AnySequence { () -> AnyIterator<SubSequence> in
            var idx = startIndex
            var prevKey: Eq?

            return AnyIterator {
                guard idx < endIndex else { return nil }
            
                let subSequence = self[idx ..< endIndex]
                    .prefix { element in
                        let elementKey = key(element)
                        defer {prevKey = elementKey}
                    
                        if let prevKey = prevKey {
                            return prevKey == elementKey
                        } else {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                idx = index(idx, offsetBy: subSequence.count, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
                return subSequence
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using it is a simple one-liner, like in this test case:

```
    struct ElementOptionalKey: Equatable {
        let key: String?
        let value: Double
    }

    func testArraySplitterOptionalKey() throws {
        let array: [ElementOptionalKey] = [
            ElementOptionalKey(key: "1", value: 1.0),
            ElementOptionalKey(key: "1", value: 1.1),
            ElementOptionalKey(key: "2", value: 2.0),
            ElementOptionalKey(key: "2", value: 2.1),
            ElementOptionalKey(key: nil, value: 0.0),
            ElementOptionalKey(key: nil, value: 0.1),
            ElementOptionalKey(key: "1", value: 1.2),
            ElementOptionalKey(key: "1", value: 1.3),
            ElementOptionalKey(key: "1", value: 1.4),
            ElementOptionalKey(key: nil, value: 0.2),
            ElementOptionalKey(key: "3", value: 3.0)
        ]
    
        // HERE is the line :-)
        let result = array.segments { $0.key }
    
        XCTAssertEqual(Array(result), [
            [ElementOptionalKey(key: "1", value: 1.0), ElementOptionalKey(key: "1", value: 1.1)],
            [ElementOptionalKey(key: "2", value: 2.0), ElementOptionalKey(key: "2", value: 2.1)],
            [ElementOptionalKey(key: nil, value: 0.0), ElementOptionalKey(key: nil, value: 0.1)],
            [ElementOptionalKey(key: "1", value: 1.2), ElementOptionalKey(key: "1", value: 1.3), ElementOptionalKey(key: "1", value: 1.4)],
            [ElementOptionalKey(key: nil, value: 0.2)],
            [ElementOptionalKey(key: "3", value: 3.0)]
        ])
    }
```

I tested it with empty collections and even with optional keys, like you have in the original question. Works well.